# Transfer Data from two different servers in ssis

Tags: ssis

My requirement is to load data on daily basis from source table from one server to destination table in another server. Both servers are different i.e one is sql server and another one is Oracle server.

what i want is to make the source query fast. Suppose today I Execute the package I should get only the new records instead of all records from source. If I read the whole table it takes much time. Even I am using Lookup transforming to check the record exists or not it is taking much time.

Please look into this

Comment: Look into what? To speed up the source query, you want to only use new records. Ok, then you will have to implement a way do identify "new records" in the source database without a lookup into the target database.

Comment: Please let me know how to identity the new records witout lookup

Comment: Maybe you could use a column to store the datetime of the last transfer.